# HTML5 concatenate checkbox com texto nome

Tags: html5, checkbox, concatenação-de-string

Bom dia pessoal,
Já fiz diversas pesquisas sobre o assunto e não encontrei nada que se referisse ao meu ambiente. Vamos lá, tenho um `Portal Captive` na empresa porém tenho dois domínios no `AD`, o sistema do `Captive Portal` não consegue diferenciar de qual domínio é cada usuário, sendo necessário colocar login o @dominio. Como solução coloquei no site de autenticação do Portal um checkbox para a pessoa escolher o domínio, porém não estou conseguindo incluir as duas informações no usuário, gostaria que fosse transparente a inclusão do domínio. Por exemplo, quando a pessoa escolher o dominioX, o próprio `HTML` colocar a informação no campo de login, usuario@dominioX.
Segue o `HTML` com a tentativa do checkbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Eventually by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bem vindo ao Portal Guest</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <h1>Bem Vindo</h1>
                <p>Para acesso a rede Wifi Guest, por favor fazer login<br /> </p>
                <font size="4">Selecione sua unidade</font><br/> </p>
            </header>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var elementoPaises = document.getElementById('paises')
            var paisesElegidos = []

            function elegirPais(element){
            if (element.checked) {
                paisesElegidos.push(element.value)
            }else{
                paisesElegidos.splice( paisesElegidos.indexOf( element.value ), 1 )
            }
            elementoPaises.innerHTML = paisesElegidos.join(', ')
            }
            </script>

        <!-- Signup Form -->
    <form method="post" action="$PORTAL_ACTION$">
        <div>
                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioX">
                <label for="contactChoice1">Unid I, III ou IV</label>

                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioY">
                <label for="contactChoice2">Unid II</label>

                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioX">
                <label for="contactChoice3">Visitante</label>
            </div>

    </fieldset>
                <! -- <input type="hidden" name="pegardados" id="pegardados" value=""> -->
                <input style=width:320px name="auth_user" id="auth_user" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required> <br>
                <input style=width:320px name="auth_pass" type="password" placeholder="Senha" required> <br>
                <!--<input name="auth_voucher" type="text"> -->
                <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
                <input name="zone" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_ZONE$">
                <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="concatenar()">
            </form>


            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vc quer por o "@dom" dentro do campo input, ou vc vai por tipo: "`<input>` @dom" com o texto fora do input (ficaria input com o texto que vai mudar do lado direito por exemplo)

Comment: Eu quero que a informação do domínio venha do checkbox, e inclua de forma transparente no campo usuário.

Comment: Transparente? Como assim transparente??

Comment: O cliente (usuário) seleciona o domínio no checkbox e depois colocar o usuário e senha, o domínio selecionado fica oculto para o cliente, e através do código ele faria isso cliente@dominioY

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro utilizar o exemplo do [BOL Mail](https://email.bol.uol.com.br/login#). utilizar um placeholder que mude conforme a seleção do usuário. Requer menos validação e o efeito visual é semelhante ao que você deseja.

Fiz uma amostra aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/joabeAlex/2fv578gm/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name=unidade]').change(function(){
    let dominio = $('input[name=unidade]:checked').val();
   $("#dominioLabel").text(dominio);
  });
});
```

```css
#dominioLabel{
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  right: 0;
  color: #999;
}

form{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 340px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" action="$PORTAL_ACTION$">
        <div>
                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioX">
                <label for="contactChoice1">Unid I, III ou IV</label>

                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioY">
                <label for="contactChoice2">Unid II</label>

                <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3"
                name="unidade" value="@dominioX">
                <label for="contactChoice3">Visitante</label>
            </div>

                <label id="dominioLabel"></label>
                <input style=width:320px name="auth_user" id="auth_user" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required> <br>
                
                <input style=width:320px name="auth_pass" type="password" placeholder="Senha" required> <br>
                <!--<input name="auth_voucher" type="text"> -->
                <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
                <input name="zone" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_ZONE$">
                <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="concatenar()">
            </form>
```

Comment: Joabe tomei a liberdade de colocar seu código direto na resposta, pois resposta com link apenas não é indicado aqui no StackOverflow

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, não sei ainda como coloca diretamente aqui para executar :)

Comment: Da uma lida aqui que vai te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim concatenar o valor do input radio escolhido com o nome do usuário da seguinte forma com **Javascript** puro:

```js
function concatenar(){
   var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')[0];
   var usuario = document.getElementById('auth_user').value;
   
   var dominio = inputs.value;
   console.log(usuario+dominio);      
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="unidade" value="@dominioX">
   <label for="contactChoice1">Unid I, III ou IV</label>

   <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="unidade" value="@dominioY">
   <label for="contactChoice2">Unid II</label>

   <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="unidade" value="@dominioZ">
   <label for="contactChoice3">Visitante</label>
</div>

   <input type="hidden" name="pegardados" id="pegardados" value="">
   <input style=width:320px name="auth_user" id="auth_user" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required> <br>
   <input style=width:320px name="auth_pass" type="password" placeholder="Senha" required> <br>
                
   <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
   <input name="zone" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_ZONE$">
   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="concatenar()">
```

> Na **var inputs** - Eu pego o input radio selecionada.
>
> Na **var usuario** - Eu pego o valor digitado no campo usuário.
>
> Na **var dominio** - Eu pego o valor do input selecionado.
>
> Depois só junto os dois valores.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Andrade, porem ele não está incluindo o @dominio no login

Comment: Na onde estaria este login que não estou vendo no código da pergunta?

Comment: Só para voce entender, no sistema que controla o Captive, ele me mostra os usuários que estão logados, com esse código que voce me mandou, ele não esta incluindo o @dominioY, só está indo a conta do cliente.

Comment: as duas informações deveriam ir junto quando clicar no botão entrar.

Comment: Mas isto é simples é so criar uma variável com os dois valores do mesmo jeito que fiz no console.log. Ficaria assim: `var pessoa = usuario+dominio`.

Comment: Desculpe te incomodar Andrade, mas não funcionou, o usuário está entrando no sistema somente com o usuário dele sem o seleção do checkbox;

Comment: Sem problemas Alan, cara eu fiz um código totalmente independente do seu código apresentado na pergunta, então eu não sei como vc está utilizando aí. Se a dúvida era concatenar o valor do input usuario com o value do radio selecionada, acredito que a minha resposta fez o resultado esperado. Precisaria ver como está seu código.

Comment: Bom dia Andrade, então, eu utilizei somente o seu código no sistema do capitve, porem depois eu faço o login pelo celular e vou olhar no controlador, só está o meu usuário sem o @dominio, ele deveria incluir os dois dados (alan@dominioY) Obrigado

Comment: Alan como disse, teria que ver seu código, se está fazendo como o meu então era pra funcionar. Veja se as variáveis estão com nomes certos, os inputs e se está concatenando as variáveis corretamente assim: `usuario+dominio`.